# Shows count value in empty cell by str_count() R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, function

I am trying to count the number of strings in a cell using str_count(). variable `names` is the column in which I want to count the number of strings separated by `","`. Below is my line of code

```
df_1$Number_count <- str_count(df_1$names,",")+1
```

When I run the above line of code, it **returns me 1 for empty cell** and **also returns me 1 if there is one value in a cell**. I don't know if I am doing something wrong, because there is no **comma ","** in empty cell.
Below is my DF

```
 S.No  names
  1    alex, dianna    
  2       
  3    annya    
  4    john, kallum, colin
```

**For S.No 2, it returns 1 and for 3 it also returns 1**

Comment: You asked the number of commas plus one. If a "cell" is empty, it contains zero commas, then you add 1 and that's what you got.

Comment: If there's uncertainty why you're getting "1" for strings that allegedly contain one comma (even after adding 1), then it would help immensely to have sample data reproducing your problem.

Comment: @nicola , in such case what could be the alternative. You can answer to the quesiton. thanks

Comment: @r2evans , I have added the example df. thanks

Comment: Your sample data is not representative, as _this_ data produces counts of 2, 1, 1, and 3. Please provide _representative_ data by providing the results of `dput(head(df_1))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The str_count() function counts the occurrences of a pattern (in your case commas) in a string. When there is an empty cell or a cell with only one value, there is no comma present, so it will return 0 occurrences. You will always get 0 + 1 in that case.

Use an ifelse statement to check for empty cells instead:

```
library(stringr)

# Sample data
df <- data.frame(names = c("alex, dianna", "", "annya", "john, kallum, colin"))

# Count the number of strings in each cell
df$Number_count <- ifelse(df$names == "", 0, str_count(df$names, ",") + 1)

# Result
df
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could include `trimws` in your `ifelse` to guard against blank-space non-empty strings

Comment: True, but without knowing the actual dataset you could implement a whole host of measures to prevent possible errors that may or may not exist with the data. This answer was only meant to provide a solution to the question.

Answer (score 1):

As str_count lets you use `regular expressions`, it might be more elegant to count the number of strings instead of the number of comma's.

```
df <- data.frame(names = c("alex, dianna", "", "annya", "john, kallum, colin"))
df$Number_count <-  stringr::str_count(df$names, "\\w+")
df
#>                 names Number_count
#> 1        alex, dianna            2
#> 2                                0
#> 3               annya            1
#> 4 john, kallum, colin            3
```